# roomba script for closed questions didn't run today

Tags: bug, automatic-deletion

The [ROOMBA script for closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519) always has been running at like 3AM UTC. However, I noticed that it didn't appear to have run today. It's 7:38AM UTC currently. Was there a change made to when/how it is run? Or did a bug happen that caused this not to run today?

Comment: IIRC if there is heavy load, and a maintenance script takes longer than usual, it is terminated. The next time it is run to completion it should catch up.

Comment: Tag scores didn't update either; looks like the server was rather overloaded last night.

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing your [roomba] tag wiki+excerpt

Comment: @S.Morgenstern yes. There are 3 different roombas. The closed questions one is ran every single day. The 30 day old and year old roombas are only ran once a week though.

Comment: Roomba must have become [self-aware](https://twitter.com/selfawareroomba).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The roomba script ran like usual today, cleaning up closed questions that fit the auto-deletion process rules. So nothing has changed with the process/timing of the closed questions roomba script.

Assuming that [HugoRune](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286092/roomba-script-for-closed-questions-didnt-run-today#comment155341_286092) and [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286092/roomba-script-for-closed-questions-didnt-run-today#comment155350_286092) were likely correct in their assumptions that the script just didn't run this one time because of heavy load on the server or something similar.

Comment: It didn't run on Sunday April 19th, 2015 either. :(

Comment: Didn't run on Monday June 29th either :( :(