# How can one do more than 40 down-votes per day?

Tags: support, downvotes, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, rate-limiting

I have been reading about Stack Exchange dying due to negative atmosphere, lack of fairness and civility:

- http://www.r-bloggers.com/are-high-reputation-users-quitting-stack-overflow/
- [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

I wanted to do some research of my own, so I ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/431779/550451/downvoters). It's trivial and lists users by the amount of downvotes.

To my surprise, [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3041194/crabolo) that is at the top of the list has ~45 downvotes per day from the time he registered (he registered 2 years and 2 months ago, he has 35485 downvotes, 35485/(2*365+2*30) = 44.917721519 downvotes per day).

**I thought the limit is 40 votes per day. Where is my math wrong?**

**EDIT:** After reading some comments: I don't think that down-voting is bad in itself this was just a start of query. I tried combining it with not having basic editing badges like 'Editor' or have done no reviews or not raised any flags but still have huge down-vote counts. I am certainly not pointing fingers as we live in mostly free world and people are smart and if they downvote they have good reason to do so.

On the other hand - to those who do feel bad to be on the top down-vote list: **Do not do anything that you wouldn't want to see on first page in newspaper.**

Comment: Deleted posts don't count towards the limit but count on the voting numbers, I believe. Peer pressure everyone into deletion with your downvotes and you can have infinitely many :)

Comment: Do automatic downvotes from flagging count towards the limit?

Comment: @JoeW automatic downvotes from flagging? There isn't such a thing is there?

Comment: @Gimby Yes, some flags do also include an automatic downvote, the spam flag is one of the flags that does it.

Comment: @JoeW: the vote is attributed to Community User, not the flagger.

Comment: Darn, *just* outside the top 100. I must apply myself more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters diamond lets you catch up really fast - just vote on posts you delete. Yannis at Programmers bragged about casting over 100 votes one day (not that I complain:)

Comment: I didn't make it on the list :(

Comment: Inappropriate title - did you mean 'per hour'?

Comment: If you add a computed column to your query, such as `u.Downvotes / DATEDIFF(dd, u.CreationDate, getdate()) as DownvotesPerDay`, this will be computed for you without the math in the OP.

Comment: Ironic that Stack Overflow was supposedly "dying" back in 2014, but it's still going strong in 2016 with loads of new questions every day.

Comment: I really don't think its fair to point people out...this post sucks -1.

Comment: `ORDER BY DownvotesPerDay DESC`: [link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/432572/downvoters)

Comment: Yay I'm like #50 ish

Comment: @JonH: This post isn't a witch hunt and voting history is a matter of public record. It's a simple, straightforward question about how one may cast more than 40 downvotes in a single day. If the linked user has any reason to be "ashamed" of their voting history then they shouldn't vote like that. +1

Comment: @CodyGray: Shame they're all terrible. We have vastly different definitions of "going strong". _Quantity is irrelevant._

Comment: @pref I completely agree with you. I *did* make that list of the top 100 downvoters, although I'm not as high as I would have expected. My point was that even with everyone complaining about how mean we are, they don't stop asking their crappy questions.

Comment: @CodyGray: Indeed. Just goes to show how vampirific these people are, and why the deadly cycle exists: "You downvote all the time! You're all so mean, but can you just solve this new problem for me please? *downvote*" rinse and repeat. I don't see it being solved - we've hit saturation. The glory days are over. Buy shares in a tropical island

Comment: How dare anyone post a question that nears or crosses the invisible border lines of StackExchange question etiquette.  But not to worry, legions of Stack Exchange RPG players will spring into action, dutifully pouncing on the offender, taking the opportunity to burnish their stats a bit more.  The hapless question poster meanwhile is left behind in the dust, wondering what just happened...

Comment: It's funny that I noticed this today, as my co-worker was just saying that he never answers questions on SO because everyone is, and I quote, "brutal". That guy is smart, too, so I think any atmosphere that makes a person like him not want to contribute needs worked on.

Comment: @Nikki9696: there is no positive way to say "sorry but your answer is wrong". If your co-worker perceives downvoting a bad answer as "brutal" and therefore we should not do that, how is the next person with a same question know which answers are considered 'good' and which ones are not?

Comment: @Jongware ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601) :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Votes on posts deleted this day [don't count for limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124818/165773), that's how one can cast over 40 votes a day.

Users who have noticeably more than 40 votes cast a day on average likely vote on posts eligible for [automatic-deletion](/questions/tagged/automatic-deletion) (aka roomba). Deletion scripts run in the morning GMT and if one votes on posts to be deleted this day, they have their limit recovered after scripts run and delete posts they voted on.

(As for downvotes from flags, these get attributed to [community-user](/questions/tagged/community-user), not to flagger.)

Comment: note to readers: **[do not miss another answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316307/839601)**. It presents matters from bit different perspective (of a flagger) and lays out some very valuable considerations

Answer (score 8):

The user currently on top of your query has *almost* just as many helpful flags ('and counting' probably).
[Votes on deleted posts do not count toward your daily max](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124818).
I think it is very likely these 2 are related (in the context of getting more than 40 downvotes a day).

*Automatic downvotes* from flags like *spam* and *rude/abusive* are contributed to [community-user](/questions/tagged/community-user),
**BUT** if you downvote something (that is/gets flagged for example NAA (optionally by you)) then that downvote is attributed to **you**.
This is not only for NAA but *also* for spam and rude/abusive (so yes, if you flag for example *spam* then the post gets -1 from community user and on top of that you can give it another -1 from yourself, totaling -2).

Now if such a post is deleted (usually due to a mod/review decision resulting from a flag) *on the same day*, then your vote is available to cast again (and you get your 1 rep back).

If one finds something worthy of flagging (as in: it's clear that it's so bad that the flag will surely be helpful) then the post clearly deserves to *float to the bottom with your downvote* (pending deletion). Such voting also (at least theoretically) helps the system evaluate how it 'trusts' the (new) user and there are also badges (like the 'well-received question'-series) related to that.
So such voting is not negative behavior but quite the opposite.

The 'down-side' is that although the rep and vote are returned to you (for such deleted posts as described above), the down-votes are still linked (and visible) to your account making such users *seem* like debby-downers, even tough they might have never ever downvoted anything that wasn't flagged-and-deleted cr*p.

Comment: "If one finds something worthy of flagging (as in: it's clear that it's so bad that the flag will surely be helpful) then the post clearly deserves to _float to the bottom with your downvote_..." - I would upvote this twice if I could. Excellent reasoning, wish more flaggers follow it

Comment: @gnat: thanks. I later also found: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286092/roomba-script-for-closed-questions-didnt-run-today which in hindsight explains the angle of your answer. But for future reference I wanted to outline what I think is a more common reason (compared to picking posts from a automatic deletion list/query) and more accurately explain what type of votes do and don't attribute to your account. I do wonder though (for quite some time now): has anyone ever proposed to make a split in the stats? Like say "# up/down-votes of which # helpful 'janitorial' votes"?

Comment: I don't recall such split stats; if memory serves there were stats that there are too few downvotes at all. So probably split stats would simply tell that there are too few downvotes of both kinds.

Comment: @gnat: The system (and most of the community) clearly see a 'behind the scenes' distinction between 'janitorial' downvotes and 'contributing' up/down votes on on-topic content. However the stat's displayed on a users's profile page make no such distinction, making 'janitors'(marshals) look (to the un-informed) like either 'debby-downers' or worse: 'strategical downvoters'. I'm not saying you don't deserve these vote-counts (like the reverted vote-'token' and rep) but I wonder what the impact might be of splitting the downvotes into 'janitorial' vs 'contributing' (possibly that reveals to much)

Comment: ... on the other hand, such a split might just result in an increase of 'janitorial' downvotes.

Comment: I see. You might be interested in this MSE discussion: [A badge that rewards “prophetic” downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134551/165773)

Comment: @gnat: good relevant link with good arguments (although I would also vote against that proposal), however 'my' idea is completely different: such a badge would be 'hidden' somewhere while the downvote numbers (up/down on Q and A and total) would still be prominent on the user's profile. Joke: *Two knights in armour (constructive SO members) walk through the dessert and encounter a Lion (user/noob un-informed in the way's of SO) upon knight A says: 'Don't worry, I read that Lions don't like canned meat' to which knight B responds: 'but I worry that that lion never read that book' (meta)..*