# Where can I see how many votes I have left for the day?

Tags: support, voting

I know there are 40 votes limit per day. I only got reminder when less than 5 
 votes left.

Is there somewhere I can see how many votes left today?

Comment: The number of votes you've already cast that day (and also that week and month, as well as all time) are listed in your [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11263560/recnac?tab=topactivity), is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I can only find the whole votes number in activity, I wanna know how many votes left today. @DavyM

Comment: @recnac 40 - (votes cast today) is not that hard... is it?

Comment: Well yeah, I was just thinking though you could do `40 - Today'sVotes` to get the number of votes left for today. But now that I think about it, that's not completely reliable because 1) The votes 30 to 40 only are able to be used when enough have been used on questions that day, and 2) The number there can be inflated because [deleted posts still count in that number, but your votes per day limit is decremented when a post you voted on that day gets deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316085/7795130). So a "votes left today" would be more useful than the activity tab's value.

Comment: Votes on non-deleted posts can be seen in your profile's Activity tab, on `?tab=votes`. I guess you can count how many there are since the last 00:00 UTC.

Comment: interesting question about votes limit. I am solely aware of the limit of questions raised per day, week and month.