# Why does Hot Meta Post show different upvote number than the actual question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-bulletin

The Hot Meta Posts form shows the upvote number as 3, but the actual [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382690/) stands at 10.

[image]

This hasn't occured to me before. Is this a bug, or is it intentional?

Comment: [It's not working! Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).